# Need to upload sub-dirs and their contents, not just files in current dir

Tags: python

A script was supplied to me in order to upload files to a cloud bucket.  You input the dir where the files you want to upload are and bingo bango, done.

What needs to happen is that there are additional sub dirs with their own files in them that I would like to transfer as well based on the input of the root dir. They would need to retain their tree structure relative to the root dir input.

Using the current code I get a write error/access denied fail.  I know this is because the for loop is using os.listdir which can't parse the extra sub dirs and files but I'm not sure how to modify.

I attempted to get all the information I needed using os.walk and parsing that out. I verified with some print tests that it was looking in the right place for everything.  However I hit a wall when I got this error when running the script:

```py
folder\folder\lib\ntpath.py", line 76, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I understand that something is being generated as a list when it shouldn't be but I'm not sure how to go about this...

This is the original script provided to me below. I have added the variable at the top just to be a little less abstract.

```py
    local_directory_path = 'C:\folder\folder\sync\FROM_LOCAL_UPLOAD'

    def upload_folder_to_cloud(self, mount_id, local_directory_path):
        ''' This method will list every file at the local_directory_path and then for each,
        it will call the api method athera.sync.upload_file for every file in your local directory
        '''

        _, destination_folder = os.path.split(local_directory_path)
        if not destination_folder:
            self.logger.error("Make sure the provided 'local_directory_path' does not end with a '/' or a '\\'")
            sys.exit(2)

        destination_folder = destination_folder + "/"
        self.logger.info("Folder = {}".format(destination_folder))
        for filename in os.listdir(local_directory_path):
                    destination_path = destination_folder + filename
                    filepath = os.path.join(local_directory_path, filename)
                    with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
                        _, err = self.client.upload_file(self.group_id, mount_id, f, destination_path=destination_path,)
                        if err != None:
                            self.logger.error(err)
                            sys.exit(4)

        return destination_folder
```

This is what I modified it to as a test:

```py
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_directory_path):

            srcFile = (os.path.join(files))
            srcRoot = (os.path.join(root))
            rootSplit = os.path.normpath(srcRoot).split(os.path.sep)
            srcDirs = '/'.join(rootSplit[4:])
            src = str('fixLocalFolder') + '/' + str(srcDirs) +'/'+ (files)
            dst = str(srcDirs) + '/' + (files)

            destination_folder = str(srcRoot) + "/"

            destination_path = str(destination_folder) + str(srcFile)
            filepath = os.path.join((str(srcDirs), str(srcFile)))
            with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
                _, err = self.client.upload_file(
                    self.group_id,
                    mount_id,
                    f,
                    destination_path=destination_path,
                )
                if err != None:
                    self.logger.error(err)
                    sys.exit(4)

            return destination_folder
```

I do not code for a living so I am sure I am not going about this the right way. I apologize for any code atrocities in advance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do see some issues in that code, even without testing it. Something like the following might work for that loop. (Note! Untested!).

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_directory_path):

    # Iterate through files in the currently processed directory
    for current_file in files:
        # Full path to file
        src_file = os.path.join(root, current_file)
        # Get the sub-path relative the original root.
        sub_path = os.path.relpath(root, start=destination_folder)
        # Get the destination path
        destination_path = os.path.join(sub_path, current_file)

        with open(src_file, "rb") as f:
            _, err = self.client.upload_file(
                self.group_id,
                mount_id,
                f,
                destination_path=destination_path,
            )
            if err != None:
                self.logger.error(err)
                sys.exit(4)
```

I believe your central problem was misunderstanding what os.walk gives you. It gives you listing of each directory (and subdirectory), one after another.

Thus the values of one iterations might look like (when listing /mydir):

```
# First iteration:
    root = "/mydir"
    dirs = ["subdir", ...]
    files = ["something.doc", "something else.txt"]
# Second iteration:
    root = "/mydir/subdir"
    dirs = ["sub-sub-dir1", ...]
    files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown and the suggestion. I'll dive in again and see if it gets me what I need. Cheers!